# Summing elements of numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, rowsum

I have an numpy array

```
>>> clf_prob.dtype()

array([[ 0.05811791,  0.06526527,  0.06024136, ...,  0.06972481],
       [ 0.06093686,  0.06357167,  0.06462331, ...,  0.06999094],
       [ 0.08188396,  0.08504034,  0.0820972 , ...,  0.08487802],
       [ 0.05197106,  0.0786195 ,  0.15669477, ...,  0.0893244]])
```

I'm trying to add elements of these arrays such that my output would be:

```
[[0.05811791 + 0.06526527 + 0.06024136 +...+ 0.06972481],
[0.06093686 + 0.06357167 + 0.06462331 +...+0.06999094],
[0.08188396 + 0.08504034 + 0.0820972 + ...+  0.08487802],
[0.05197106 + 0.0786195  + 0.15669477+ ...+ 0.0893244]]
```

I tried doing

```
sum(map(sum, clf_prob))
```

This doesn't gives me desired output.
Any suggestion?

Comment: `np.sum(clf_prob, axis=1)` (or try axis=0 if you don't like that!). Sometimes the `keepdims` parameter is handy - try it.

Comment: What is the desired output?  Maybe use a smaller array so you can show all the data and the expected output.

Comment: clf_prob=array([[2,3],[3,1],[4,3]])  ............          desired output ([5],[4],[7])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
clf_prob.sum(axis=1)
```

This will take the sum over a certain axis, in this case rows.

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.sum()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) over your intended axis (1) should do the job in your case

Comment: this will result in one number which is sum of all elements,specifying axis=1 gives a columns wise sums,axis=0 row wise

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan I meant he should look at the way numpy sum works.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Another probability is to use ufunc of numpy:
`np.sum.reduce(clf_prob)`
which will give the sum over the first axis. You can also use the `axis` parameter to sum over another axis.